# Narrow sonar report to modified files

Tags: sonarqube

I know about property `sonar.analysis.mode` and their values: `analysis`, `preview`, `incremental`

But that's not exactly what I would like to get.

So my problem is:

I have a project which is being developed few years from now. So there is pretty many issues (like 10K+).

I would like do something similar to incremental mode, but at the same time I would like to suggest to developer some old issues which are really close to the places which he was modifing to fix they by the way.

For example suppose I have duplicated code and this is an old issue. Task which was assigned to me force me to change one of these duplications. It would be pretty great if report could contain info about this duplicate so I could fix these issue since I probably need to edit other duplications.

It hasn't be that accurate it would be acceptable to print all issues from modified files for example.

So is there a way to achieve this? For example with some inclusions/exclusions or any other mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem, an application with years of development behind it that we are now using SonarQube to review.  There are a lot of legacy issues that we can't dedicate time to remove (the application is working as-is, after all) but we don't want to add new issues with current work.

Rather than asking SonarQube to give me a report, we have adopted the convention that developers should review any code they're modifying for issues that can easily and safely be resolved.  That resulted in about 8% reduction in legacy violations last year, with no specifically dedicated time.

We do the review of code undergoing revision either with the GUI, by drilling down into components until we get to the source file, and view the violations there, or using the Eclipse plugin.  Most of the team prefers the Eclipse plugin, which will show you issues in your work in progress, as well as existing issues.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Delegating code review to programmers is probably really good way to go. However I pretty often have a new guys... so I don't really expect them that they will do good code review. So I would like Sonar to automate for me pointing violations out to the programmer. So that he will be sensitive when it's about code quality.

Comment: If you haven't looked at the plugin, take a look.  It integrates so the issues look just like compiler issues (unused variables, for example) in the IDE.  There's both inline marking on the editor page and a separate view with list of issues.  It may do what you're looking for.

Comment: I knew about that posibility. Unfortunately in our company we're using NetBeans. :( I really would like to get all of this inside IDE. But with NetBeans I don't see the way.

Comment: There appear to be several netbeans plugins available, according to a quick google for "sonar netbeans".  One of them might work for you.